# change host header of existing web application in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis

How can we change the host header of the existing web application without extending it in SharePoint 2013 . My requirement is to create two web applications on port 80 , one with host header and one without host header but when i try to do that i get the error message saying

```
The IIS Web Site you have selected is in use by SharePoint. You must select another port or hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you have to do

- Update the AAM via central admin with the URL
- update the IIS bindings with new host headers for the web app(on all web front ends)

Now you will be able to create new Web application on port 80.